# What makes a difference to the meaning of the text with "borrow" and "access"?

Tags: terminology

My confusion with these two terms comes from the following text:

So, when the required target language item is unknown and the learner **borrows** an L1 substitute, the consequence is an L1 transfer error, but when the learner knows the target language item but fails to access it, and instead **accesses** an L1 substitute, we have a case of an L1 interference mistake.

I then searched online and found that "borrow" implies that a L1 item will be used in a target language situation without any change to the item.

But I still feel confused with the text.

Answer (score 3):

As with most terminology, these terms are used in different ways by different authors. But judging from this particular passage, I gather that this author uses ***borrow*** for when the speaker only has an L1 version of a word and deliberately uses it as a suboptimal substitute for the target word. The author uses ***access*** when the speaker knows the target language (L2) version of the word but inadvertently uses the L1 word instead (presumably because L1 "rolls off the tongue" more easily).

An analogy: The ***borrow*** case would be if you needed to hammer a nail but all you had in your toolbox was a screwdriver, so you deliberately grabbed the screwdriver and used it to bang on the nail (not its intended purpose). The ***access*** case would be if you had both a screwdriver and a hammer in your toolbox but you were working too quickly and so you accidentally grabbed the screwdriver.